# tezos-baker-004 no usual output

Tags: baker, solo-baking, baking-node

Updated my node and ran the new protocol clients. Node synced and works normally, the same with accuser . But baker client give me the normal start:

```
Waiting for the node to be synchronized with its peers...
Node synchronized.
Baker started.
May 30 21:37:42 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.baking: No slot found at level XXXXXX
```

But no output after that for the next blocks as usually does. Endorser also doesn't work. Starts normally:

```
Waiting for the node to be synchronized with its peers...
Node synchronized.
Endorser started.
```

But nothing happens and I just get missed endorsements. I don't know what else can I check since I updated the whole node. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one single node running? Does "tezos-client bootstrapped" give you a timestamp not older than a minute? Is your OS time correct?

Comment: What do the log of the node say? Does the node receive blocks regularly? Does it "switch" to the newly arrived head?